# Is it possible to launch custom application from Windows Phone 8.1 call log?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I have a use case for Windows Phone 8.1: user would like to search for records with phone number of a missed  call in my custom WP app. There are URI associations in WP, but apparently no way to integrate into phone's call log. Are there any wor karounds to get information from phone call history (log)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call log history is not available to general purpose (as opposed to OEM and Mobile Operator) apps on Windows Phone.

You can request or vote on features such as this on the Windows Platform Dev Feedback site at http://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform?query=call%20log%20api .

--Rob